# Make __call metamethod as iterator

Tags: lua, iterator, meta-method

I'm trying to emulate execution of certain functions from scripts of other app. That app have Lua library which contains function `list()`, it returns table where key is string UUID and value just string, like `local tbl = { "0000..-0000-..." = "someString", etc... }`. That table can be iterated in for loop, like

```lua
local lib = require("someLibrary.lua");

for key, value in lib.list() do
    -- do something with keys and values, like print
end

-- or it can be used like this

local tbl = lib.list();
for key, value in tbl do -- tbl works as pairs(tbl) and works exactly how code on top
    -- do something with keys and values, like print
end
```

So the question, how do I implement __call metamethod to work as pairs() or next() etc.?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes! I've managed to find answer to my question. I've found source code of library that I trying to replicate. It actually uses local variables to iterate through table

Here is a code how I made `lib.list()` and `lst` work

```lua
function lib.list(filter, exact)
    if filter == nil then filter = '' end;
    if exact == nil then exact = false end;

    local list = Component.list(filter, exact); -- just gets table from app that written in C#, treat like someClass.getSomeTable()

    local list_mt = {}; -- metatable that assigns to above "list" table
    local key = nil; -- key that will be used in iterator

    function list_mt.__call() -- __call metamethod for "list" table
        key = next(list, key);
        if key then
            return key, list[key]
        end
    end

    return setmetatable(list, list_mt); -- return table with assigned metatable that contains __call metamethod
end
```

Answer (score 0):

`pairs(tbl)` returns `next,tbl,nil`.

So do

```
setmetatable(tbl,{__call=function (t) return next,t,nil end})
```

and then you can write

```
for key, value in tbl() do
        print(key, value)
end
```

I don't think you can avoid the `()` there.

Comment: I don't know why, but that variant with "next, t, nil" makes it loop over and over, like in infinite loop

Comment: @craftersmine, Make sure to write `tbl()`

Comment: Hmm.. In the app (actually, it is a mod) `tbl` with out `()` is works, I will try `next, t, nil`

Comment: Well it only works if I writing `tbl()`, but if I write `lib.list()` instead or just `tbl`, it doesn't work, `lib.list()` and `tbl` returns table as value.

Comment: To make lib.list() work, I tried to `return pairs(tbl)`, but then of course `tbl` or `tbl()` stops working because I returning `next, tbl, nil` instead of actual table